'save' does not support bucketBy and sortBy right now
I am trying to apply bucketing on my dataframe when saving it on HDFS using command bellow.
df.write
  .format("parquet")
  .bucketBy(200,"groupIdProjection")
  .sortBy("groupIdProjection")
  .option("header", true)
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .option("path",  conf.assiette.work.prep.transitionMatrixObligor)
  .save()

When running my job, I have got this error message :

'save' does not support bucketBy and sortBy right now

Note that I am working with 3.3.0 as a spark version and 2.12.12 as a scala version
And the cluster is running on AWS

Replace save to saveAsTable as Bucketing and sorting is only available to persistent table.
df.write
  .format("parquet")
  .bucketBy(200,"groupIdProjection")
  .sortBy("groupIdProjection")
  .option("header", true)
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .option("path",  conf.assiette.work.prep.transitionMatrixObligor)
  .saveAsTable("bucketDemoTable")


I am looking for a solution without saveAsTable because I am just looking to store the dataframe in hdfs without having a table name.

@user24123007 You can't. The sorting and bucketing info is saved in the table metadata/properties, and there is no equivalent in plain HDFS.
